# Convert UUID back to String input - nameUUIDFromBytes

Tags: java, hash, uuid

I am using the function `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[])` [1] to convert a string to UUID. Is it possible to convert back to the original string once I've got the UUID?

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#nameUUIDFromBytes-byte:A-

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's the Class description of UUID

> UUID is an immutable representation of a 128-bit universally unique identifier (UUID).
>
> There are multiple, variant layouts of UUIDs, but this class is based upon variant 2 of RFC 4122, the Leach-Salz variant. This class can be used to model alternate variants, but most of the methods will be unsupported in those cases; see each method for details.

So when you call `nameUUIDFromBytes (byte[] name)`, it will return `an UUID instance` which is, again, a immutable representation of a 128bit universally unique identifier.

This means the byte is now hashed into a unique identifier and will not be reversible into the original byte.

What's the purpose of hashing bytes and why do you want to reverse it? If you specify that in your question, I will EDIT this post to give further help. But for now this is the answer.

Comment: I am pretty sure its not required to state 'why' he/she wants to reverse the conversion.. . the question was specifically "how" do you do it....thats it.

Comment: @Saehun Sean Oh  Is there any way to get original value ? I want to add UUID (UUID of sensitive information) into url. Is it possible to hacker to get original value ?

Comment: @Vijay if the hacker has all the time of the universe with great computing power (great as in beyond supercomputer), maybe. But it's designed to be irreversible.

Answer (score 5):

Name-based UUIDs use a hash function to map an input string to a fixed number of bits. Hash functions are lossy and are not generally reversible.

Comment: You said, "not generally reversible.". 
I am using this (UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[])) method. Is it possible to get original value ? Is there any way to get original value ?

Comment: No, there is no way. `nameUUIDFromBytes()` hashes the string (which you presumably convert to `byte[]`) using the one-way `MD5`.

Answer (score -9):

Imagine you have this:

```
 UUID uuid = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[]);
```

To convert to a `String` it's simple, just use the `toString()` method:

```
String original = uuid.toString();
```

Comment: That doesn't give you the name.

Comment: String before conversion = 000059dba6073a0000000b40411988
UUID = bfab57e7-d89c-300a-9934-64060b959736
UUID.toString = bfab57e7-d89c-300a-9934-64060b959736

Comment: This won't work. Actually uuid.toString() will return an immutable string.